# Older higher-spec bike vs newer lower-spec bike

Tags: road-bike

I am choosing from a choice of used bikes. For the same price I could get a higher-spec bike that is maybe around 9 years old (at the most) or a bike that is 3 years old but lower-spec.

The older bike is in good condition; I am asking more from a technology development perspective. Also the frame on the older bike is fully carbon whereas the frame on the newer is either cheaper and still carbon or aluminum frame with carbon forks.

Comment: This is a "how long is a piece of string?" question. Without knowing a lot more details, it's impossible to answer, and even then, the answer that makes sense for me might not make sense for you.

Comment: Answers in answers, please.  Comments are for clarifying and improving the question.

Answer (score -1):

The prime reason for picking one bike over another is comfort.  Could be the old bike is more comfortable for you than the newer one.  An uncomfortable bike won't be ridden as much or as far.

We can't tell you which bike is more comfortable, you have to try them both out yourself.

Whether one is higher spec is a later question - an uncomfortable bike is already eliminated IMO.